# How can I access a component's class properties from another component with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I create a class like

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

let foo = new Foo('baz');
console.log(foo.bar); // baz
```

I am able to access the `.bar` property without issue. However, I have the following code split into two React components (trimmed for clarity):

A `Card` Component

```js
class Card extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.name = props.cardData.name;
        this.image = props.cardData.image_uris.png;
    }
}
```

A `Search` Component

```js
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fuse = null;
    this.state = {
      show: false,
      query: null,
      pool: [
        <Card cardData={{ name: 'test', image_uris: { png: 'https://i.imgur.com/or94i38.jpg' } }}></Card >,
        <Card cardData={{ name: 'test', image_uris: { png: 'https://i.imgur.com/or94i38.jpg' } }}></Card >,
        <Card cardData={{ name: 'test', image_uris: { png: 'https://i.imgur.com/or94i38.jpg' } }}></Card >,
        <Card cardData={{ name: 'test', image_uris: { png: 'https://i.imgur.com/or94i38.jpg' } }}></Card >,
      ],
      results: null
    }

    this.getResults = this.getResults.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fuse = new Fuse(this.state.pool, {
      keys: ['name']
    })

    for (let x of this.state.pool) {
      console.log(x.name); // undefined!
    }
  }
```

I'm unable to access the properties which I defined earlier on the `Card` component, but I'm not sure why. I've tried creating getters & moving the properties outside of the constructor to no avail. I'm sure I'm missing something simple with React or JS in general, but what?

Comment: The JSX syntax (`<Foo ... />`) creates a React element. A React element is not actually an instance of the class, it's a descriptor for how to instantiate the class. You can access the actual instance (and therefore its properties) via refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html . Having said that, there might be a better way to achieve what you want. What do you need the properties for?

Comment: @FelixKling Well that makes a lot of sense! Are refs for this purpose strictly bad practice? I'm struggling to think of a way to implement this functionality otherwise... Thanks

Comment: @FelixKling I'm trying to implement a search component that can search a few different arrays of Cards. I have a `Player` component which has arrays of `Card`s: `library`, `exile`, and `graveyard`. The idea is to have a generic `Search` component that can fuzzy-match a `Card`'s name in any of the aforementioned arrays against user-input and then filter the `Card`s displayed. The full code is here if it's of any use: https://github.com/Naught0/mtg-play-test & I must warn you I am a novice developer :)

Comment: You should just store card objects (`{name: ..., image_uris: ...}`) as data in your state, perform any computation on those objects and only render them "at the end".

Comment: Okay so rather than pass the `Card` component (which is NOT actually an instance of the object), I should just pass the data and render it after. I think I got it maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. Per Felix's comment on my OP, I realized that my problem was how I was thinking about state and data flow in React in general. I was passing around Components rather than data.

Rather than use Refs (improperly) or add a new dependency, I opted to pass the data through state and props to the child component, and then render the data afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data (Property Values) between components using observables (service oriented). This will assign the component property value(s) to an object that is then passed through subscription to another component that has subscribed to that observable.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new Subject();

export const messageService = {
    sendMessage: message => subject.next({ text: message }),
    clearMessages: () => subject.next(),
    getMessage: () => subject.asObservable()
};
```

Then your component code:

```
 componentDidMount() {
        // subscribe to home component messages
        this.subscription = messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
            if (message) {
                //Do stuff if you have the observable content
            } else {
                //Do other stuff is there is no observable content
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have no idea what any of this means honestly. I'll have to read up on rxjs -- thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it. React only able to pass data to its `parent to child` but never be able to pass data from `child to parent` nor `node to siblings` (as far as I know).
so the way on how you would do it probably you will use Redux or you can also make a Global Variable you name it as storage and define your property for your component in that store. later on any data which you will pass you will refer to this Global Variable. But I don't think so this is the good practice. The formal practical one that I know is by using Redux.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like I'm driving my head into the wall using React. Nothing seems to work the way I'd think coming from any other OO language...

Comment: surely, glad if it helps